# Take 2 integer inputs say x = 10 and y = 50 and print in the format 10,20 20,30, 30,40 and 40,50

Tags: python-2.7

```
x = int(input("Enter the start Number:"))
y = int(input("Enter the end number:"))

while(start < end):

    start = start + 10
    new = start + 10
    print start, new
```

Please someone help me out.
I want the output to be like

```
10,20
20,30
30,40
40,50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like that?

```py
start = int(input("Enter the start Number:"))
end = int(input("Enter the end number:"))

while(start < end):
    print start, start + 10
    start = start + 10
```

Comment: Yes thats what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, another question. What if I have 2 large integer inputs lets say 356785 and 456785. I want the the output to be displayed in the intervals of 1000 starting from the start till end. Something like this: 356785, 356885 356885.356995.....and so on till the end number

Comment: start = int(input("Enter the start Number:"))
end = int(input("Enter the end number:"))

for n in range(start, end, 3600):
    print(n, n + 3600)

Comment: The start = 1375070400 and end = 1375074000

Answer (score 1):

It is much neater to use a `for` loop and `range` if you already know how many times you will be looping:

```
start = int(input("Enter the start Number:"))
end = int(input("Enter the end number:"))

for n in range(start, end, 10):
    print(n, n + 10)
```

Comment: Lets say start - 1375070400 and end = 1375074000 and I want for n in range(start, end, 3600): print (n,n + 3600). This is not working. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Are you supposed to be printing in tens? If so, you should leave the third argument to `range`, the `step`, at `10`.